# Ignoring bright motion from an image

Tags: c#, opencv, graphics, computer-vision, emgucv

I am currently trying to write a C# app that will detect motion.  For a 'blob' motion, if the object is of high luminance then ignore it.  I do this to remove moths/bugs that come close up to a camera.  At nighttime this works well.  To distinguish whether the image has been taken at night I reduce the image to 1px by 1px and get the saturation and luminance.  I have said a low saturation then a darker image.  However, when I look at an image taken in the evening the saturation is also low and if I wear a white shirt, the motion code thinks the white shirt is of high luminance and rejects the image.

It seems that the color white is also mistaken for a high luminance.

Is my approach wrong?  Is HSV the correct way to determine objects of high luminance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thresholds for luminance and saturation will have to be different for different times of day. A statistical approach, where you determine these by using several images for different times of day, might be helpful.

If your camera has automatic gain/white balance control, that too will cause problems.

Comment: thanks for your response.  That is the approach i am using now. And as you noted yhe automatic gain/white IS havin a disruptive affect. I will have to monitor the saturation and luminace during the 24 cycle to get a bearing of the lighting as to when the motion was detected. I just wanted to check i was not missing a more obvious/simpler solution.